# Normalizing Matrix wrt Exponential

Tags: functions, exponential-function, optimal-transport

I have a matrix, for example $M = \begin{bmatrix}300&100\\20&5\end{bmatrix}$, and I want to use $e^{-M}$ as a distance function. Computationally, numbers such as $e^{-300}$ are rounded to zero, so I want to transform $M$ into $M'$ with all its elements in $[0,1]$ and the property that the ratio of the negative exponential for any two elements is the same in $M$ and $M'$. For example,$\frac{e^{-300}}{e^{-5}} = \frac{e^{-f(300)}}{e^{-f(5)}}$ where $f \mapsto [0,1]$.

I have tried setting this problem up as finding $f$ s.t. $\frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-y}} = \frac{e^{-f(x)}}{e^{-f(y)}}$ which transforms into $f(x) - x = f(y) - y$. However, I am unsure how to proceed from here.

Comment: If you mean that $f : \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \to [0, 1]$ is a map such that $x - y = f(x) - f(y)$, then this is impossible because $|f(a) - f(b)|\le1$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, so $2 = 3 - 1 \ne f(3) - f(1) \le 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I suspect you're trying to implement the Sinkhorn algorithm in a numerically stable way.

In that case you are constructing a kernel $K := e^{-\frac{C}{\varepsilon}}$, where $C$ is some cost matrix and division by a regularization constant $\varepsilon>0$ is meant elementwise.

So if elements in $C$ get large, elements in $K$ get closer to zero and numerically you might get underflows.

One important thing here is that $K$ is not the cost matrix, but $C$ is - and since the *absolute* cost from one unit of mass to another is not important for our transport problem, but only the *relative* cost, we can rescale $C$ by some factor, for example divide it by the largest value in $C$.